# Copying GZipStream to file

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, gzip, gzipstream

I want to decompress a file that was uploaded encoded with gzip to S3 straight to a file stream.

Here is my method that returns the gzip stream after decompressing the S3 stream:

```
using var stream = await _s3.GetObjectStreamAsync(_processServiceOptions.BucketName, key, null);
using var gzipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress, true);
await WriteToFileAsync(gzipStream);
```

I'm trying to use it like so to copy it directly to the file stream, instead of loading it into memory using another stream...

```
async Task WriteToFileAsync(Stream data)
{
    using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
    {
        await data.CopyToAsync(fs);
    }
}
```

However I'm getting `System.IO.InvalidDataException: The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.`

Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps the error is correct? How was the file compressed? Have you tried downloading it and opening it with a compression tool? Is it a single GZ-compressed file or a ZIP file?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The file is uploaded to S3 using the `Content-Encoding=gzip` header. When I load the stream into a `BinaryReader` it works just fine.

Comment: Which means it's not fine at all and the file is uncompressed. Setting a header doesn't compress the payload. You wouldn't be able to read a compressed file with BinaryReader

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos S3 takes care of that. Tried and tested.

Comment: And yet here you are. The very fact you can use BinaryReader means that the response is *un*compressed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But I'm using BinaryReader on the gzip stream, *after* it decompresses the original (S3) stream...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer (I know I did), I opted for a different solution. I decided to make a generic compressor that can be used anywhere you need a byte[] compressed. You are doing a little more work because you are reading and writing from a stream twice, and optimizing that is left as an exercise for the reader, but compressing generically is a really elegant solution altogether.

Here's one for GZip:

```cs
public class GZipCompressor : ICompressor
{
    public async Task<byte[]> CompressAsync(byte[] data, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using var uncompressedStream = new MemoryStream(data);
        using var compressedStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var compressorStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            await uncompressedStream.CopyToAsync(compressorStream, cancellationToken);
        }

        return compressedStream.ToArray();
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> DecompressAsync(byte[] compressedData, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(compressedData);
        using var decompressorStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        using var decompressedStream = new MemoryStream();
        await decompressorStream.CopyToAsync(decompressedStream, cancellationToken);

        return decompressedStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And here's one for Deflate:

```cs
public class DeflateCompressor: ICompressor
{
    public async Task<byte[]> CompressAsync(byte[] data, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using var uncompressedStream = new MemoryStream(data);
        using var compressedStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var compressorStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            await uncompressedStream.CopyToAsync(compressorStream, cancellationToken);
        }

        return compressedStream.ToArray();
    }

    public async Task<byte[]> DecompressAsync(byte[] compressedData, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using var compressedStream = new MemoryStream(compressedData);
        using var decompressorStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        using var decompressedStream = new MemoryStream();
        await decompressorStream.CopyToAsync(decompressedStream, cancellationToken);

        return decompressedStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Now you just call this before sending your data to AWS and you're golden.